# Is this sentence grammatically sound? "He was thus capable of great erudition."

Tags: grammar

> "He was thus capable of great erudition."

The phrase " ... capable of great erudition ... " is confusing me. I am not sure of the context regarding this; it might be an aphorism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it.

*He was capable of great* ***X***. (Feats of strength, evil, jocularity, compassion, acts of mercy.)

Many words and phrases cannot be substituted in this construction, but **erudition** can be.

**erudition** (Merriam-Webster online): "extensive knowledge acquired chiefly from books : profound, recondite, or bookish learning"

Examples:

*a scholar of remarkable* ***erudition***
*a theologian of impressive* ***erudition*** *but with a down-to-earth manner*

Your phrase means that he has the potential to become very knowledgeable. It's something that would normally only be said in formal speech or literature.

Comment: TY. That promptly resolved the issue. :)